# Why don't iTunes URL links work?

Tags: macos, itunes

Whenever I get an iTunes link, like:

```
http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewPodcast?id=333256858
```

it never opens up in iTunes. I get the "One Moment Please, connecting to the iTunes store" message, but iTunes never gets focus or goes to the link location.

This has been happening for at least a year for me. It used to work (albeit slowly).

I wonder if it has to do with another iTunes problem I'm seeing: Cmd-Tab app switching does not give focus to iTunes. I have to click on the window to switch to it. And if it's hidden, I have to use Expose to find it. Even clicking on the iTunes icon in the dock doesn't do it.

I'm running Mac OS X 10.5 Leopard, iTunes 9.0(70)

Comment: Well, there's a new iTunes version out - 9.0.2. Maybe try uninstalling the version you have and installing 9.0.2?

Comment: I'm now running Snow Leopard (10.6.2) and iTunes 9.0.2. Still happening. What I haven't tried yet is a wipe of my HD and fresh install of the OS.

Other data point: This only happens for my user account. Other user accounts on my machine do not do this.

I tried trashing my iTunes preference files, but that didn't solve either problem.

Comment: I notice that iTunes links work fine in Google Chrome, so it must be something with my Firefox settings. Which means the app-switching problem is unrelated. I'm going to open a new question for that.

Comment: Trying that link in Google Chrome on Windows 7, I noticed something that might be relevant to the issue.  Does the focus-changing issue occur with any other applications?  I noticed that when the link is clicked in chrome, focus shifts to a dialog asking whether or not to launch iTunes.  Perhaps this is failing to take focus in the same way that iTunes is?

Comment: 1. The focus-changing issue only happens with iTunes.
2. I have it set up such that Chrome/Firefox do not show a dialog asking whether to launch iTunes or not - they just launch iTunes. Or, rather, Chrome does but Firefox does not.

Answer (score 1):

The link is forcing the browser to ask that the local machine start iTunes to handle the request. Depending on your browser/OS settings, this may not be allowed, and the request will fail.

What web browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using Firefox 3.5.3. And it seems to work for my friends who use Firefox on the Mac. 

Also, iTunes is already running, so it doesn't have to start it up.